# Avoid using Cookie when entering a password protected Wordpress site?

Tags: php, wordpress, cookies

is there a way to avoid using a Cookie when a User visits a password protected Site on Wordpress?

I only found the possibility to turn the Cookie into a session Cookie but I want to avoid it completely:

```
function f( $expires){
return 0}
add_filter( 'post_password_expires', 'f');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [ini_set()](https://www.php.net/ini_set):

```
ini_set('session.use_cookies', '0');
```

Or in your php.ini file:

```
session.use_cookies = 0
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your comment!
I added now the following to my function.php:

`
function sessTest($expires){
return 0 ;
}
add_filter('post_password_expires', 'sessTest');
ini_set('session.use_cookies', '0');
`

but still getting the Cookie. Where did I fail?

Comment: Your ini_set dosen't need to be inside a function. And ini_set should be at top before everything else.

Comment: thanks, it worked, I had to adjust the function which changes the cookie to a session cookie.

If I may ask, do you have any idea how to unset the wordpress_test_cookie ?

Comment: if (isset($_COOKIE['key'])) {
    unset($_COOKIE['key']);
    setcookie('key', '', time() - 3600, '/'); // empty value and old timestamp
}

Comment: I had a similar solution, but the cookie keeps coming back after entering a password protected site :(

it disappears only for a sec

Comment: If you set this in your php.ini session.use_cookies = 0, you will never have cookies on your site.

Comment: But this will also prevent other plugins that use cookies to set cookies too, or?